# node - How do I save the token returned by the POST request into a variable

Tags: node.js, request, http-post

I need to be able to save the token returned by the POST request so I can decode it and send it   back with my other requests. I can only console log the token but could find no way of saving it to a variable. How do I go about doing this? Am I thinking of this problem all wrong?

```
const request = require('request');

const options = { method: 'POST',
url: process.env.AUTH_URL,
headers:
{ 'cache-control': 'no-cache',
'content-type': 'application/json',
api_key: process.env.API_KEY,
client_secret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID },
body: { userName: process.env.USERNAME, userPassword: process.env.PASSWORD },
json: true };

async function authenticate(options) {
    try{
        console.log('inside try');
        const reqToken = await request(options, function (error, response, body) {
            if (error) throw new Error(error);
            console.log(body.token);
        });
    } catch(error) {
        throw(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: if the request is in backend then store it in session or in a cache. if the request in a browser then stores it in local storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either `promisify` the `request` or simply use `axios` which supports promise out of the box.

```
async function authenticate(options) {
  try {
    console.log("inside try");
    const reqToken = await new Promise((res, rej) => {
      request(options, function(error, response, body) {
        if (error) rej(error);
        res(body.token);
      });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

OR using axios:

```
async function authenticate(options) {
  try {
    console.log("inside try");
    const { data:{ token } } = await axios(options);
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

Comment: The fist one worked, I can console log reqToken but nothing show on the return statement. What could be causing it?